# Always getting null when trying to call entity using includeProperties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple get like this:

```
var tc = _pService.Listar(includeProperties: "Estatus,CatalogosRegistro");

if (tc != null)
{
    List<VehiculoGetViewModel> tiposcargas = new List<VehiculoGetViewModel>();

    foreach (var item in tc)
    {
        var carga = new VehiculoGetViewModel()
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            Nombre = item.Nombre,
            NombreEstatus = item.Estatus.Nombre,
            NombreContenedor = item.CatalogosRegistro.Nombre
        };

        tiposcargas.Add(carga);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have `includeProperties` where I  use `Estatus` and `CatalogoRegistro` tables.

So when I call `NombreEstatus = item.Estatus.Nombre`, item.Estatus.Nombre get value correctly but `item.CatalogosRegistro` always come null

**View Model:**

```
public class VehiculoGetViewModel
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string NombreEstatus { get; set; }
    public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }
    public string NombreContenedor { get; set; }
    public CatalogoRegistro CatalogosRegistro { get; set; }
}
```

**Model**

```
[Table("TiposVehiculo", Schema="adm")]
public class TipoVehiculo: Entidad<Int32>
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public int EstatusID { get; set; }
    public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }
    public CatalogoRegistro CatalogosRegistro { get; set; }
}
```

**Listar implementation:**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Listar(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
        }
```

Strange thing is I don´t have any problems using `Estatus` and I use same structure to call CatalogoRegistro but it always come null, can some one know what is wrong there? Regards

**Update:**

After checing query of `var tc = _pService.Listar` it just throwing all values of inner join with `CatalogosRegistros`

[image]

And that is because I don´t have `CatalogosRegistros_ID` I just have an `TipoContenedorID` column. Why EF change name of my ID?

So if I change to `TipoContenedorID` I get correct values:

[image]

Comment: `Listar`?  Where is that implemented?

Comment: Sorry, I update my question with `Listar()` implementation @juharr

Comment: Your problem is most likely the translation from IQueryable to IEnumerable, which, IIRC, executes the query and stores the result in memory

Comment: Instead of the `Includes` and the `AsEnumerable` and iterating the results like that why not just  `Select` the desired results at part of the query?

Comment: How can I do it with select instead include? can you explain me with example? @juharr

Comment: Can you look at your `"TiposVehiculo"` table in the database if it contains a column called `"CatalogosRegistro_Id"` and it's populated with the correct data.

Comment: No, it don´t have nothing starting with `Id` into `tiposVehiculo` table and `Estatus` table haven´t got it too @IvanStoev

Comment: It's looking like there's an issue with how your Entities are setup.  Did you do DB first or code first?  Also you probably need to just ask a new question about how your Entities are setup and include all the code in your context that sets up the relationships.

Comment: Code first, alright I will do it

Comment: Personally I avoid code first (unless I do code first, but create the code from an existing DB) because it's very easy to mess stuff up that way.

Comment: So at the end you **do** have `CatalogosRegistro_Id` column in `TiposVehiculo` table with no data in it (see my previous comment:) It's because of the default EF name convention. To use properly Code First with existing database, you need to learn how to map existing tables, columns and relationships with data annotations and fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't pass a filter or order by to `Listar` you don't really even need it.

```
var tiposcargas = _pService.Select(item => new VehiculoGetViewModel()
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Nombre = item.Nombre,
        NombreEstatus = item.Estatus.Nombre,
        NombreContenedor = item.CatalogosRegistro.Nombre
    }).ToList();
```

This way if `Estatus` or `CatalogosRegistro` are `null` because there isn't a matching row in those tables it will just give you `null` for the `Nombre`.  You may have to use `??` if `NombreEstatus` and `NomberContenedor` are not nullable.

Personally I'd drop using the `Include` and `AsEnumerable` and and just return the resulting `IQueryable` and let the caller deal with `Includes` or just using navigation properties in their select.

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Listar(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: I review your answer, but I cant make drastic changes to my entity, it´s a big application, so if I change it, all runing methods going down, there is not another form to solve this? It´s imposibble call two properties?

Comment: It´s the same if I only call CatalogosRegistros like `_pService.Listar(includeProperties: "CatalogosRegistro");` it just throwing null, like something with calling model is wrong

Comment: If you're determined to keep using `Listar` as it is you'll need to handle the possibility that the navigation properties that you include can be `null` like this  `NombreContenedor = item.CatalogosRegistro?.Nombre ?? 0` or if you don't have C# 6 then `NombreContenedor = item.CatalogosRegistro == null ? 0 : item.CatalogosRegistro.Nombre`

Comment: But I´t does´t be to come null... it don´t calling CatalogosRegistros table, so because it , it is throwing null

Comment: Have you checked the SQL query that it generates?  Just because you include a navigation property doesn't mean it will not be null because of a missing reference from one table to the other.

Comment: @Ledwing FYI you can get the query from a profiler or by calling `ToString` on your `IQueryable` before calling `AsEnumerable` on it.